# How can I set assembly look-up path after initiating CLR?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, clr

Is there a way (an API function) to set the C# assembly lookup path after starting CLR Host, so that, [ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164411.aspx) function find it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are only [two ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx) to specify an assembly's locations.

Unfortunately, none of them works for this case. Thereby, having the possible lists of assembly's directories and the name of the assembly, one needs to locate the file manually and then pass the full path to ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain() function.

However, I still do not understand why such capability is not provided in CLR api (or maybe it is, but not properly documented).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. Basically the `AssemblyResolve` event gets called every time the path to an assembly cannot be found. You then have the opportunity to manually load that assembly.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += 
  new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

private System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender,
  ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
      string name = args.Name;
      //You can return null if you don't know how to load this assembly
      return Assembly.LoadFrom(SomeFunction(name));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you obork! However, I'm looking for a method to set the path of assemblies (the bunch of directories which contain the target assembly) so that the call of ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain() find and load it automatically.

Comment: Added another option to my answer

Comment: The CLR does not look into the `PATH` environment variable when [probing for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) (loading) assemblies.

Comment: but, is there a way to pass it the directories for probing?

Comment: Hmm... So it probably was in my code to load unmanaged dlls... Sorry for that